# Boost program options with default values always present when using vm.count()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I've been trying to validate my passed options with boost::program_options.  My command has several modes, each of which have associated params that can be specified.  What I'm trying to do is ensure these associated params are passed with the mode, i.e.

```
unicorn --fly --magic-wings-threshold
```

Where `--fly` is the mode and `--magic-wings-threshold` is an associated param.  What I've noticed is if `--magic-wings-threshold` has a default value, e.g.

```
("magic-wings-threshold,w", po::value<double>(&wings_thresh)->default_value(0.8, "0.8"),
           "Magic wings maximum power"
)
```

then I can't use

```
if (vm.count("magic-wings-threshold")( {
    // do stuff
}
```

to detect if the user passed that param.

It appears that default value params are always passed and detected in `vm.count()`.  Does anyone know a workaround or alternative?

Comment: All the unicorns i'm familiar with do not fly and have no wings.  Perhaps you were thinking of Pegasus?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use [`boost::program_options::variable_value::defaulted()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/program_options/variable_value.html#id1132213-bb)

```
if (vm["magic-wings-threshold"].defaulted())  {
    // assume defaulted value
} else {
    // one was provided
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solution works, there is no way to tell the
-k  vs no -k

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell difference between

```
-k option not provided
-k provided
```

You should use po::value()->**implicit_value**(), You can tell the different situations with:

```
-k option not provided  ->  vm["k"]==0  
-k option provided      ->  vm["k"]==1
```